# how to fit the original text format of a paragraph into the html paragraph element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a client comment section page on my website and I want the exact format being entered by the user to be shown into the page. Here I'm using the paragraph element with more less link using jQuery. My problem is if the user enters long sets of paragraph, it displays beyond the width and height of the paragraph element and the original format is not retained. I want to auto-adjust the area of the paragraph element according to the area of the paragraph being entered by the user. How do I fix this?

jQuery/Javascript:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var minimized_elements = $('p.minimize');

    minimized_elements.each(function() {
        var t = $(this).text();
        if(t.length < 120) return;

        $(this).html(
            t.slice(0,120)+'<span>... </span><a href="#" class="more">More</a>'+
            '<span style="display:none;">'+ t.slice(120,t.length)+' <a href="#"      class="less">Less</a></span>'
            );

    });

    $('a.more', minimized_elements).click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).hide().prev().hide();
        $(this).next().show();

    });

    $('a.less', minimized_elements).click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().prev().show().prev().show();

    });
});
```

CSS

```
.more {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 10px;
}

p {
    padding: 0 0 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<p id ="content" class="minimize more"  style ="width :500px; height :100px; white-space :pre "> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Comments").ToString() %> </p> 

//where the content of the paragraph came from the database being queried as comments.
```

Comment: I suppose your 'p' get a 'display:block' from somewhere. I think using '_min-height:100px_' instead of 'height:100px'would work from what I can understand.

Comment: @Kraz,thanks for the suggestion this works adjusting the area of the paragrph element when removing white-space:pre but the original format is lost because it will compress all words into one paragraph.How do I retain the original formats being entered by the user considering its indentions and spacing of each paragraph?

Comment: Since it's about user input (from a text area I suppose), replacing `\r\n` and others line-delimiters with `<br />` should work. Same for extra spaces (using `&nbsp;`). Could replace tabs (\t) with 2-4 &nbsp; too...

Comment: @Kraz, thanks it does formatting but there's a little thing it bypasses its indention every paragraph.Does it possible to include its indention setting?

Comment: string comment = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />"));

Comment: I'm using C#,how do I apply the indention or the extra spaces(using &nbsp;) in that codes?

Comment: You mean, this? : `TextBox2.Text.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"); TextBox2.Text.Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");`

Comment: @Kraz, How do I combine both codes from my code above and your could so both could work?

I tried something like this 

string comment = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br />") + TextBox2.Text.Replace("\t", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
but it has no effect for the tab spaces for indention...How do I do this? Thanks

Comment: Since the comments were getting numerous, I re-wrote what I said and made you a little demo too. It should answer your last question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The original issue

To make the section where your comment appears scale with content length, you need to replace the following html:

```
<p id ="content" class="minimize more"  style ="width :500px; height :100px; white-space :pre ">
```

to (`min-height`)

```
<p id ="content" class="minimize more"  style ="width :500px; min-height :100px; white-space :pre ">
```

Your `p`, who's normaly an element with a `display:inline` property, is turned to `display:block` somehow.

#### The issue in the comments

Text taken from a text area doesn't contains html. Line breaks, extra spaces (more than 1) and tabs are encoded as such and ignored by browsers. As such, you need to replace them with html to display them correctly.

as such,
`\r\n`, `\r` and `\n` (line-break) become `<br />`
`\t` (tabs) become `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`
  (spaces) become `&nbsp;`

I've made a [little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5azBJ/) for you to toy with.

(Replacing the characters will work in either php or javascript)